# How do microseconds work in a datetime.timedelta?

Tags: python, python-datetime, timedelta

In the example below - I'm getting a value for seconds that do not match the microseconds. It is baffling me. Can anyone shed a light?

```
>>> a
datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 13, 21, 47, 46, 837435, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> b
datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 13, 21, 47, 54, 724570, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> (b-a).microseconds
887135
>>> (b-a).seconds
7
>>> (b-a)
datetime.timedelta(seconds=7, microseconds=887135)
```

Comment: Looks correct to me. Exactly what numbers are not matching?

Answer (score 1):

Microseconds is not the delta in microseconds, it is the non-integer reminder in microseconds.
The time difference is 7 seconds and 887135 microseconds

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that (b-a).seconds is not supposed to the equivalent of (b-a).microseconds. The exact time difference here is (b-a).seconds + (b-a).microseconds.